# 'React' is declared but its value is never read in ts 4.2

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Just upgraded to typescript 4.2.2 and started receiving following warning for all my react imports i.e.

```
import React from "react";
```

Causes this warning

> 'React' is declared but its value is never read

This import was working fine before and is required to use jsx as far as I am aware. I looked at  the change log, but didn't see any changes related to this new warning. My tsconfig also has `"jsx": "react-jsx"`

Any advice on how to resolve this?

Comment: I believe you are using React 17, where you don't need to import `React` anymore

Comment: If I remove it I get an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined` I think it is only optional with certain babel configuration, so keeping  it in should still be valid?

Comment: yes, there's some babel config to adjust you can check here https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#manual-babel-setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case I had no access to babel, however was able to fix this via following webpack plugin

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      React: 'react'
    })
  ]
```

Comment: what file should the above goto ?

Answer (score -1):

I used `React.Fragment` to solve this issue.

```js
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      ...
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33616140)

Answer (score -4):

add:

```js
export default React.memo(YourComponent);
```

Answer (score -4):

You can disable this error check globally by opening the tsconfig.json file and setting the noUnusedLocals property to false.

Comment: You still want linting to check for unused locals, just not this unused local. Don't disable this property to fix a standard React unused local error like this.